# CSS-stylable popup (modal) that doesnt load until it is opened

Tags: javascript, css, html

so I'd like to build something like [That](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp).
Now I want to put a LOT of these buttons on a page and every popup must contain a different `<iframe>` (embedding videos). Also I'd liek them to be CSS-stylable.
So what I cant seem to achieve is two things:
- I cant find any script (I'm extremely new to web thingys) that will open DIFFERENT popups for different buttons
- I cant find something that lets the contents of the popups remain unloaded until they are actually displayed.

Thanks for any help!

PS: I only know how to use jS, HTML and CSS so I cant use fancy stuff... First project...

-edit-
Okay, i didnt know server-side things are related to this. I can use PHP (actually I'd populate the popups per PHP) so is there a way using the specified languages plus PHP? and if not, how can I achieve the other goal I specified? I have no idea of JS, I just know how to use scripts...

Comment: You can't really keep from having the content loaded somehow, if all you want to use is js,html and css. It will have to be on the page, just in hidden containers. You can place them outside the viewport, set them as `display: none;`, but they will still be part of the markup. If you want them to load depending on what you click on, you will have to use some sort of server-side language, and maybe query the content with AJAX/javascript. (Click a button, js loads the content via AJAX, and displays a modal with the content)

Comment: You can use JavaScript to place the `<iframe>` into the page once the button is clicked. The `.html()` function could be used to place the `<iframe>` into a `<div>` so that it would load only after it has been placed into the page.

Comment: Okay, i didnt know server-side things are related to this. I can use PHP (actually I'd populate the popups per PHP) so is there a way using the specified languages plus PHP? and if not, how can I achieve the other goal I specified?

I have no idea of JS, I just know how to use scripts...

Answer (score 0):

hope this link will help:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

plz recheck your data-target="#exampleModal" in button is the id of the modal and put iframe instead of this form in this link.